# Angular 4 NgOnInitReference Error

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to open a new page upon the page startup but I keep getting a

> Reference Error: Window not defined.

I've only started working with TypeScript and Angular4 recently, so I'm not so sure which one of the two this problem really falls under.

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

testCall: Window;

constructor() {      
  this.testCall = new Window();
  this.testCall.open(
    "https://static.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg");
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  console.log("function read");

  window.open("https://static.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg");
}
```

Even if I use the `this.testCall.open` inside the `OnInit()`, I'll only get a Reference Error, but on the `open` method.

I know it's a simple page open when the first page opens but its been a week already and I really have no idea how to do this in the typescript/angular4 setup.

Answer (score 0):

Delete this line

```
this.testCall = new Window();
```

`window` is a global variable in JS, just calling `window.open('url')` should open a new window.

Comment: You need to delete that line. If the message stays, then you didn't delete it.

Comment: Of course I deleted that line. Except now it's giving me "TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined" Really sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Please read my answer. I've posted your solution, and by 2 times you proved you didn't read it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try declaring the `window` object in the file that contains HomeComponent?. if not, try declaring it as;

```
declare var window: any;
```

on the top of the file (after imports).

TypeScript doesn't know about window as we are not providing any typing info on that. In that case, we can declare those to tell the typescript compiler that the `window` reference in the global namespace didn't originate from a typescript file.

Read more about this scenario [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2013/07/22/quick-tip-typescript-declare-keyword/)

Answer (score 0):

Okay apparently window does not exist the server, which is why ngOnInit() and constructor() throws an error when I try to put the "window.open" there

```
import { Component, PLATFORM_ID, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';

export class HomeComponent {   
submitted: boolean = false;

constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) {

}

ngOnInit() {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
        window.open("URL");
    }
}
}
```

This worked perfectly for me.